# OSM Export attributes of streets

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, fields-attributes, export

Hi I am beginner at QGIS. I am trying to export the attributes "surface" and "parking lane" of every street of the city Dresden.

I tried it with "overpassturbo", but it doesn't give me every street, only few. If i try to export with the OSMExport command, i have to minimize my area, it doesn't work for the whole area of the city.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't give you every street like you said? Do you have an example? Can you share the overpass turbo link? What is the OSMExport command? Do you have a link for this one?

Comment: https://imge.to/i/Ux7rr (Screenshot) and http://overpass-turbo.eu/# (Link)

Comment: Can you improve your initial question with these information. I guess the link is something link http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/K8K Your link is the link to Overpass turbo without the query. Can you show us an example of street which is not returned by the query? I had a quick look, everything seems ok.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is for the wrong key. According to [Key:parking:lane](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:parking:lane) you need to query for keys `parking:lane:both`, `parking:lane:left` and `parking:lane:right`. You only need to look for ways and can skip nodes and relations.

This is the resulting Overpass query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “parking:lane:*”
  way["parking:lane:both"]({{bbox}});
  way["parking:lane:left"]({{bbox}});
  way["parking:lane:right"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/KaU

Maybe this query can still be optimized, however I'm not an Overpass API expert.